# Debian Harddrive Fdisk - Same ID's and changing letters

Tags: debian, hard-drive, ntfs

I am trying to create and install a debain NAS and ive been having a hard time because I am new to all of this. I used ntfs-3g in order to automount my 4 NTFS drives. I also have a partitioned harddrive which is for the OS.

When I was working on it and I ran this command I got this:

**fdisk -l**

- /dev/sdae1

**fdisk -l | grep NTFS**

- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdc1
- /dev/sdd1

The weird thing is, all of the NTFS harddrives listed had an ID of 7.

The next time I boot up my machine, I get an error about mounting /dev/sda1 and I run this command, and get the following results:

**fdisk -l | grep NTFS**

- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdc1
- /dev/sdd1
- /dev/sde1

I havent plugged in any drives, so whats going on? How to I make sure that my drives are mounted with the same sdXX name every time, and is the reason for this because they dont have unique ID numbers, if so, how do I solve this?

Comment: Why would you have NTFS filesystem on a Linux NAS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the disks via [labels or UUIDs](http://wiki.debian.org/Part-UUID).

The label approach:

Make sure you have `ntfsprogs` installed with `apt-get install ntfsprogs`. Then do

```
ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 ntfsdisk1 
... repeat for all drives
```

in `/etc/fstab` replace the `/dev/sdx1` part of the respective lines with `LABEL=ntfsdisk1` etc.

Comment: ntfslabel is an unknown command. How should I be renaming them?

Comment: See my edit, you are missing a package.

Comment: Also, I would consider your general approach with NTFS formatted disks less than optimal.  Why don't you build a software RAID (RAID 6 or 10) with a Linux filesystem and export it via Samba? Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: As in, to have NTFS formatted disks is dumb? I should use linux formatted disks and then use samba to send it over?

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do this, I would say it's misguided (dumb is such a harsh word :)) . With a RAID, you loose in total capacity, but win in reliability because your data is not lost if a single disk fails.